# Show More Show Less - Not Working

Tags: jquery

There a 'load more/load less' function running on this page which I'm attempting to debug. https://maes-mynan.cogitoprojectx.com/holiday-homes/the-llewellyn-lodge-lodge/

You can see it the section with the heading "More About The Llewellyn Lodge"

The text is displayed via an ACF WYSIWYG field.

As far as I can see, the code is set to truncate the text after the fourth paragraph and on-click show the full text. 
However, instead of just truncating the text, it seems to remove the fourth paragraph entirely.

In essence, it displays paragraphs 1 - 3, [misses 4] and then displays paragraph 5 onwards.

Here's the jQuery function.

Grateful for any help, on how to simply truncate the text after the fourth paragraph.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('.read-more2').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).children('p').length>4){
    jQuery(this).children('p:lt(3)').show();
    jQuery(this).append('<button class="loadMore btn btn-primary">Show More</button>');
  }
});
jQuery('.read-more2').on("click",'.loadMore',function (){
    jQuery(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p:gt(3)').show(); // use gt instead of lt
    jQuery(this).removeClass('loadMore').addClass('loadLess').text('Show Less');
});
jQuery('.read-more2').on("click",'.loadLess',function () {
    jQuery(this).parent('.read-more2').children('p:gt(3)').hide(); // use gt instead of lt
    jQuery(this).removeClass('loadLess').addClass('loadMore').text('Show More');
});
```

});

Comment: Hi Nate K, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about pure Javascript off-topic so you might notice some down-votes. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This might be better asked on the main stackoverflow site.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for the pointer. Makes more sense to add this on the main StackOverflow site.